# Check if value from given list in sql is existing in table - SQL

Tags: sql, database

i have a little problem with checking if some products in prestashop from the list are existing in our shop or not. For one product is easy, we can check in backoffice but when we want to check for example list of 100 products it is problematic.

I have a query like that

```sql
SELECT ps_product_lang.name, 
ps_product.reference, 
ps_product.active AS `Czy aktywny` 
from ps_product  
INNER join ps_product_lang ON ps_product.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product 
WHERE ps_product.reference NOT IN 
("test1","test2","test3")
```

but this shows all records that are not in that list. How to check if a product from list is not in the table and return for example "not listed" or something like that?

Results of query are like that
[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BXQ4.png)
But i want to check only which elements that i present on the list are not in database, like i would write "wrongtestcode" in the list it would result in showing only "wrongtestcode" in query results

Comment: Could you please add some example lines for both tables and also add the desired result for the query you are looking for? Your description is difficult to understand. I guess you are looking for a left join, but it's not sure.

Comment: Hello, i added a screenshot and maybe better explanation. I just want to return result that will check if something from my given list are not present in database. The one i did actually shows every record from table that is not in the list.

Comment: For me, this is not clear enough. You could use this site to provide sample data and then share the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/ But maybe someone else can help you even without further details.

Comment: ps_products contains all products from the shop with symbol reference (the list "test1" or "AKSA-XXX" in screenshot) 
I want to check what products from list that i have from other program are not present in the shop so for example when i have that whole lists of products "AKSA-XXX" i want to return only results that will check and show me that "AKSA-XXX" are not present in database. I don't know how to explaint it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image doesn't really help I'm afraid but I think you need to know about LEFT OUTER JOINS and NULL values. I think these code samples will help explain.

Firstly this is my demo data

```
declare @list1 table (id int, itemname varchar(30));
insert into @list1 (id, itemname) values
(1, 'item 1'),(2,'item 2'), (3, 'item 3'),
(4, 'item 4'),(5,'item 5'), (6, 'item 6');

declare @list2 table (id int, itemname varchar(30));
insert into @list2 (id, itemname) values
(1, 'item 1'),(4,'item 4'), (6, 'item 6');
```

As you can see List 2 only contains 3 of the items that are on List 1.
To list items that are in both lists do as you have already done and use and INNER JOIN

```
select l1.id, l2.itemname
from @list1 l1
INNER JOIN @list2 l2 on l1.id = l2.id;
```

But to list items from list1 that are NOT in list2 you need to use and OUTER JOIN and check for NULL values coming from List 2

```
select l1.id, l1.itemname
from @list1 l1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @list2 l2 on l1.id = l2.id
WHERE l2.id IS NULL;
```

A LEFT outer join lists every record on the left side of the join (the first table listed in the FROM clause). If there is a matching row on the right side of the join (the next table in the list, i.e. List 2) then we can get the values from the matching row, but if there is no match then SQL returns NULL as the value. We used that in the WHERE clause above, but we can use it in other ways.

E.g. To list all items with indication of whether in list 2 or not - this will list every item and next to each will show either the name on list 2 or the words "Not in list 2"

```
select l1.id, l1.itemname, ISNULL(l2.itemname, 'Not in list 2')
from @list1 l1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @list2 l2 on l1.id = l2.id;
```

Alternatively, for neater output, this will only show "Not in list 2" next to the missing items and blanks for matching items

```
select l1.id, l1.itemname, 
CASE WHEN l2.itemname IS NULL THEN 'Not in list 2' ELSE '' END as [Flag]
from @list1 l1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @list2 l2 on l1.id = l2.id;
```